# Multiple directives in a controller, only one can display at any time

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a controller here and two directives:

```
app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.audioOptions = {
                        audio: [{
                          file : "sound/world.mp3",
                          type: "mp3"
                        },
                        {
                          file : "sound/world.ogg",
                          type: "ogg"
                        }],
                        playOnclick : true,
                        playOnload: true
                      };
 $scope.textOptions={
                       text : "Bird",
                       audio: [
                        {
                          file : "sound/world.mp3",
                          type: "mp3"
                        },
                        {
                          file : "sound/world.ogg",
                          type: "ogg"
                        }],
                        playAudioOnClick : true
                     };                      
});

app.directive('rsTextComponent',['ngAudio',function(ngAudio){
   return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{options:"=options"},
    controller:function($scope){
        //click to play
       $scope.playTextAudio = function(){
         if($scope.options.playAudioOnClick)
            {
                 ngAudio.play(audioCurrent);
            }
       }
    },
    template:'<div class="textbar" ng-click="playTextAudio()">{{options.text}}</div>'
};
}]);

app.directive('rsAudioComponent',['ngAudio',function(ngAudio){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{options:"=options"},
    controller:function($scope){
        //click to play
       $scope.playAudio = function(){
         if($scope.options.playOnclick)
            {
                 ngAudio.play(audioCurrent);
            }
       }
    },
    template:'<div class="audiobar"><button ng-click="playAudio()">PLAY</button></div>'
};
}]);
```

Then I render it in list.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <rs-audio-component options="audioOptions">
  <rs-text-component options="textOptions">
</div>
```

Seems all are ok, but the problem here is that, when I start to browse list.html, only one directive can render and display, the other one disappears. it's wired.
Below are the steps I tested:

When I comment out the rs-audio-component element and keep rs-text-component in list.html, then rs-text-component works properly.

When I comment out the rs-text-component element and keep rs-audio-component in list.html, then rs-audio-component works properly.

But when I keep them two in list.html, only rs-audio-component can display, rs-text-component disappears.

Would anyone give some light? thx.

Comment: After wrapped the rs-audio-component and rs-text-component with li element, all are worked properly for me ? why? Why should I wrap elemnts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the directive tags.  It is the XML way. `<rs-audio-component></rs-audio-component>`